# Admob set position?

Tags: android, position, admob, andengine

I added admob adds in my game without xml.and I wanna set position where I want.It's only get some positions like Gravity.TOP or Gravity.BOTTOM and so on... How can i set it with coordinates I want?

Comment: AFAIK You can only do that with Absolute Layout, which is not recommended by Google.

Answer (score 1):

```
mAdView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "ZZZZZ");
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.fl1);
layout.addView(mAdView);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, android.view.Gravity.BOTTOM|android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


layout.addView(mAdView,Params );
mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

try this.

Comment: i already did like yours.I want to put coordinates which I want.Like (10,10)  not Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL

Comment: then you have to use Absolute Layout :)

Comment: how can I use it? any example?